# remove all subLayers from a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

In an animation I added a lot of **sublayers** to a **view**, with:

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer1];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer2];
```

....

I would like to remove all sublayers with an action.
I already tried with this suggestion of a similar question:

```
rootLayer.sublayers = nil;
```

but it doesn't work...

Could you help me?
Than you!

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The `sublayers` property of a `CALayer` object returns a copy of the array. Setting it no nil does nothing about the sublayers. This however will do:

```
for (CALayer *layer in self.view.layer.sublayers) {
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

Or, in Swift

```
self.view.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
```

Comment: It seems I am mistaken. You _can_ set the `sublayers` to an array prepopulated with `CALayer` objects. My solution is still correct, though. Also this oneliner should probably work (untested): `[self.view.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)]`

Comment: @SveinHalvorHalvorsen That one line does work. Its much cleaner than a loop

Comment: Plus, it's sometimes problematic to mutate an array while iterating through it. Maybe it happens to work here, but in general it can be problematic.

Comment: The `sublayers` property of `CALayer` returns a copy. However, so you're not mutating the array you're iterating over. Also, if an element of the array is no longer a sublayer of the layer by the time you call `removeFromSuperLayer` this has no side-effects unless the layer has been added as a sublayer to another layer.

Comment: Although sublayers property of CALayer has "copy" attribute, this code causes crash with more than one sublayer (trying to mutate array while enumerating it). Explicitly copying sublayers array fixes this problem: 
for (CALayer *sublayer in [rootLayer.sublayers copy]) {
          [sublayer removeFromSuperlayer];
}

Comment: For swift version,it will be better if we can add check of     ----                                  if   layer.isKindOfClass(CAShapeLayer)
   { layer.removeFromSuperlayer()  }

Comment: this threw NSGenericException

Comment: @JoeBlow I reverted your edits. There is no reason to only remove `CAShapeLayer`. The original question does not mention shape layers, and this arbitrarily restricts the layers removed to one special kind. We want to remove _all_ sublayers. The code above does not crash, and does not mutate the array while iterating.

Comment: Big Thanks for you man, a week pass trying to solve this issue. just with your code everything is okay.

Comment: Like we have `tag` in `view` is there any specific thing to identify specific layer ?

Answer (score 33):

**Swift 3.0 & Swift 4.0**

Set the `sublayers` property to `nil` to remove all sublayers from a view.

```
view.layer.sublayers = nil
```

also you can add

```
.removeAll()
```

Comment: Worked for me, Dont know any downside of doing this. Should this be used rather than calling removeFromSuperLayer() for each sub layer? May be others can comment.

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me and fixed the crash:

```
[self.view.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)]
```

I changed the view with my image `UImageview`, and the crash is gone.

Answer (score 6):

**For swift5 to remove CAShapeLayer from added view**

```
guard let sublayers = self.view.layer.sublayers else { return }

for sublayer in sublayers where sublayer.isKind(of: CAShapeLayer.self) {
        sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 2.0:**

```
    for layer: CALayer in self.view.layer.sublayers! {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
```

or

```
    self.view.layer.performSelector("removeFromSuperlayer")
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5:

You can either remove the layer itself or iterate through them and do the following:

```
layer.removeAllAnimations()
layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.1**

`self.view.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()`

or if in a UIView sub-class just

`layer.sublayers?.removeAll()`

Comment: this crashes, any ideas why

Comment: There's a gotcha here - beware that you didn't create a layer that you then subsequently try to access after removing all sublayers at another place in your code!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **delete all sublayers and add a new one**, you can easily do:

```
rootLayer.sublayers = [layer1] // adding one layer

rootLayer.sublayers = [layer1, layer2, ...] // adding two or more layers
```

This could be helpful, if you work with `tableview` or `collectionview cells`. You don't need to call `prepareForReuse` for **removing** the `sublayers`.